# Why does an asynchronous/ajax request get cancelled in componentDidMount

Tags: ajax, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, axios

So if I have an api in my `componentDidMount` lifecycle

```
constructor() {
   this.source = axios.CancelToken.source();
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('some-api-url', {
    cancelToken: this.source.token,
  });
  .then(res => {
     // set state here or do something based on response i get
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // handle error
  })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.source.cancel('request cancelled');
}
```

Coming back to my question why do I have to do this, just to avoid this error;

> Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

If I just load this component and I haven't even unmounted the component in any way why does it still get unmounted.

I am using react router, every time I switch a page using I get the `setState` error. Why do I get this error? Why do I have to cancel all subscriptions for ajax calls in componentDidUnmount?

Comment: Could you include your React Router code showing how you are using this component?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to react and anyway I am gonna answer this. This is what I think that is happening

You have to take two things into consideration. First is React and the second one is the async request which you are sending inside `componentDidMount`.

Once the current component gets mounted, `componentDidMount` gets triggered and the async request will be send. Since you are using `axios`, it will return a promise. Now the promise is waiting to be resolved (or rejected) and once that happens you will update the state.

Now when you switch to a new page, the current component will be unmounted. But note that the promise has not yet been resolved and once it gets resolved, the `then` callback will be called and the state gets updated for the component(**which has already been unmounted**). This is why you are getting the error.
If you cancel the request while unmounting, then the state won't gets updated (since we are not waiting for the promise to resolve)